# How can I prevent web apps from appearing in the launcher (waste of launcher space)?

Tags: launcher, icons, unity-dash, webapps

Every time I go to Amazon website, an extra launcher icon gets created in my launcher as long as I'm on the Amazon website. How can I prevent this icon from appearing in the launcher? It's a waste of space, because I have already a Firefox launcher icon, and the Amazon icon is nothing else than Firefox being on the Amazon website. I don't want web apps to appear in the launcher. It's enough that they are a shortcut in the dash. So How do I keep them from creating superfluous icons in the launcher?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running 12.10.  Can you do without the shortcut in the dash as well?  If you can, just uninstall that and the icon shouldn't appear in the launcher.

Comment: Thank you, I uninstalled the amazon webapp through software center. Nuisance gone.